# OpenCL Debug Assertion Failed when calling delete[]

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm getting started on openCL and I'm running into a problem with deallocating memory. Everything executes fine, my data I get back is what I expect it to be but I can't seem to call `delete[]` on my array. The code is shown below.

Calling `delete[]` on `gpu_dest` works fine but calling it on `matrix` causes an error. Looking around on SO I found that I might have changed the location of the array, but since it is only read from in this program I'm not sure where I should have done such a thing.

Could anyone enlighten me please?

The full error is the following:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...2014 - 2015\Parallel Systems\project-opencl\Debug\Project.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgdel.cpp
Line: 52
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

The code

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

#include <JC/util.hpp>

//#define A(x,y) a[x*width + y]



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try {
        if (argc != 4) {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <kernel_file> <kernel_name> <workgroup_size>";
            throw std::runtime_error(oss.str());
        }

        std::string kernel_file(argv[1]);
        std::string kernel_name(argv[2]);
        unsigned int workgroup_size = atoi(argv[3]);
        std::cout << "Workgroup size: " << workgroup_size << std::endl;

        // Initialize test matrix
        int matrix_size = 9;
        float input[9] = { 10, -7, 0, -3, 2, 6, 5, -1, 5 };
        // Allocate memory on the host and populate source

        float *gpu_dst = new float[matrix_size];
        float *matrix = input;

        // OpenCL initialization
        std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
        std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
        cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
        platforms[0].getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
        cl::Context context(devices);
        cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices[0], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE);

        // Allocate memory on the device
        cl::Buffer source_buf(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, matrix_size*sizeof(float));
        cl::Buffer dest_buf(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, matrix_size*sizeof(float));

        // Create the kernel
        cl::Program program = jc::buildProgram(kernel_file, context, devices);
        cl::Kernel kernel(program, kernel_name.c_str());
        // set the kernel arguments
        kernel.setArg<cl::Memory>(0, source_buf);
        kernel.setArg<cl::Memory>(1, dest_buf);
        kernel.setArg<cl_uint>(2, matrix_size);

        // transfer source data from the host to the device
        queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(source_buf, CL_TRUE, 0, matrix_size*sizeof(float), matrix);

        // execute the code on the device
        cl_ulong t;
        t = jc::runAndTimeKernel(kernel, queue, cl::NDRange(matrix_size), cl::NDRange(workgroup_size));

        // transfer destination data from the device to the host
        queue.enqueueReadBuffer(dest_buf, CL_TRUE, 0, matrix_size*sizeof(float), gpu_dst);

        // compute the data throughput in GB/s
        float throughput = (2.0*matrix_size*sizeof(float)) / t; // t is in nano seconds
        std::cout << "Achieved throughput: " << throughput << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            std::cout << gpu_dst[i] << matrix[i] << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Deallocating memory" << std::endl;

        // Deallocate memory
        delete[] gpu_dst;
        delete[] matrix;// <-- This causes an error, for some reason..

        std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
    catch (cl::Error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << ": " << jc::readable_status(e.err());
        return 3;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected error. Aborting!\n" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: For what I see from a quick scan through your code, `matrix` points to the array `input` which is **stack-allocated** and thus deleted automatically. Never delete stack-allocated objects manually with `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matrix` was not dynamically allocated, therefore using `delete[]` is invalid.

```
float input[9] = { 10, -7, 0, -3, 2, 6, 5, -1, 5 };
float *matrix = input;
//..
delete [] matrix;  // wrong
```

Second, why don't you use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`?

`std::vector<float> gpu_dst(matrix_size);`

Then you don't need the `delete [] gpu_dst;` at the end.

Comment: But doesn't the same go for `gpu_dest`? And that one I can delete?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer - gpu_dst was dynamically allocated using `new[]`, therefore you must use `delete[]` to deallocate the memory.  The rule is simple -- `new/new[]` must be matched with a corresponding `delete/delete[]`.